# Using int as a type parameter for java.util.Dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, primitive

When I try to declare a Dictionary as such:

```
private Dictionary<String, int> map;
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

> Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token

But it works fine with `Integer`. I'm vaguely aware that Java treats `int` / `Integer` differently (I come from a .NET background), but I was hoping someone could give me a full explanation on why I can't use primitives in a Dictionary<>

Comment: From Dictionary's javadoc: **NOTE:** This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the Map interface, rather than extending this class.

Comment: Throw that on as an answer and I'll +1 it (again)

Comment: Meh, I don't really care - you do it, I'll +1 you :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In Java primitives aren't objects, so you can't use them in place of objects. However Java will automatically box/unbox primitives (aka [autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)) into objects so you can do things like:

```
List<Integer> intList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
intList.add(1);
intList.add(new Integer(2));
...
Integer first = intList.get(0);
int second = intList.get(1);
```

But this is really just the compiler automatically converting types for you.

Comment: Hmm, so is Java less efficient than .NET here because it forces you to box the integer before adding it to the collection?  That's one of the often-stated benefits of `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` over `HashTable` in .NET -- you avoid boxing.

Comment: What is meant by "Dimensions expected after this token"? Is it referring to an array, like `int[]` which would be okay because it's an `Array` object?

Answer (score 9):

In .Net, "primitive" types are backed by objects. In Java, there's a hard distinction between primitive types and Objects. Java 5 introduced autoboxing, which can coerce between the two in certain situations. However, because the Java generics system uses type-erasure, there isn't enough information to autobox in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Java collections only allow references not primitives.  You need to use the wrapper classes (in this case java.lang.Integer) to do what you are after:

```
private Dictionary<String, Integer> map;
```

they you can do things like:

```
int foo = map.get("hello");
```

and

```
map.put("world", 42);
```

and Java uses autoboxing/unboxing to deal with the details of the conversion for you.

[Here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) is a little description on it.

Comment: I mentioned that it works `Integer` in my original post. I was hoping for an explanation on why

Comment: Isn't int[] not a primitive? It might just be expecting an array, right?

Comment: Technically, `Dictionary` isn't part of the Java Collections framework, so this doesn't really explain why `int` is disallowed in `Dictionary` objects.

Comment: Arrays are references not primitives: "A variable of array type holds a reference to an object." http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.2

Comment: Dictionary has existed in Java for a very long time, before interfaces were added (which is why it isn't an interface but it should be).  The collections framework was added in JDK 1.2 to address the lack of common collections.  So it is not part of the framework, but it is a distant relative :-)  There is no way in Java to have a variable that holds both a primitive and a reference so there is no way to make a Dictionary that works for primitives and references at the same time.  You would have to make an IntDictionary that worked on ints...

Comment: Yes, int[] works just fine:

        final Dictionary<String, int[]> foo;

        foo = new Hashtable<String, int[]>();
        foo.put("a", new int[] {1, 2, 3});
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foo.get("a")));

Comment: TofuBeer, that's all true; I was just pointing out that using Java collections as an explanation didn't really explain, since `Dictionary` objects aren't collections in the contemporary Java meaning of the term.  Your latter explanation is the real reason.

Comment: I lump dictionary in with the collections as well... they are just the "poor mans" version :-)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on TofuBeer's answer.

int is a primitive

Integer is an Object.

Generics does not support primitives.

Comment: I'd say that's more of a summary than an expansion :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=MyAdapter.class, type=int.class)
```

Thats the trick specify type to make it work with primitives

In your adapter

using the same in package-info will mean you do it globally for that package

Found this after experimenting.

```
public class MyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Integer> {
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in Java the primitives are truely primitives. In Java `int` will pass by value, while `Integer` will pass a reference. In .NET int or Int32 etc. are just different names.

Comment: Except generics are part of the compilation process- nothing is ever "passed" in the poster's example.

Comment: FYI, int/Int32 will pass by reference in .NET too since they are value types (and thus live on the stack).

Comment: Also, `int` is only an alias for `Int32` in c#. VB.NET uses `Integer`

Comment: (Correction to my own comment) int/Int32 will pass by _value_