# Is there a dictionary which accepts values of various data types?

Tags: java, types, dictionary, primitive-types

I need a map where the values are of different types, like integer, string etc. The problem with Java is that primitives here are not `Object`s which suggests that it may not be possible to have a hybrid dictionary. I want to confirm this.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001755/using-int-as-a-type-parameter-for-java-util-dictionary

Comment: You might want to share more of your design for comments. In my experience using different types of values in a Map often is a sign of less than optimal design.

Comment: I want a JSON desrializer that can create a tree, based on just the message instead of converting it into a given target class. So I want a dictionary<String,Object>(dictionary or map whatever the name may be) or a List<Object> as output like Jon Skeet says assuming automatic boxing in Java. Also assuming there is a nice JSON serialization-deserialzation library that does this. Gson for example needs a type into which the message will be deserialized into. Hence Gson is not helpful for me. Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Can you post what your dictionary/map supposed to look like and what the JSON output you exect from it?

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you just want a `Map<String, Object>` (or whatever your key type is).

Primitive values will be boxed appropriately:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

map.put("int", 20);
map.put("long", 100L);
// etc
```

Note that in order to retrieve the value and *unbox* it, you have to mention the specific wrapper type:

```
// Explicit unboxing
int x = (int) (Integer) map.get("int");
// Implicit unboxing
int y = (Integer) map.get("int");
// USing a method from Number instead
int z = ((Integer) map.get("int")).intValue();
```

Comment: Geez Jon, you really don't sleep. I was about to post the same thing. :)

Comment: Another option for numbers is Map<String, Number>

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, the OP wants a value also of type String. Number doesn't qualify.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, good point, curiously enough that Map and Dictionary non-generic would have done the job.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I need somethig like that. See my comment above to understand my problem.

Comment: @ada: Looks like you want JSONObject: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Actually I found something better.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078360/parsing-json-into-mapstring-entity-with-flexjson
FlexJSON has JSONDeserializer<Map<String,Object>> which does the job very nicely. All this time I was trying with Hashtable<String,Object> instead. Thanks for the help Jon for suggesting the interface Map.

Answer (score 3):

When you put primitives into a `Map` in Java, they get *Auto-Boxed* into their object form. For example, if you have a `Map` defined as:

```
Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

then you can use primitives of type `int`, as they will be auto-boxed into an `Integer`.

As for your original question, defining a `Map` as such:

```
// using Integer for key type, can be something else
Map<Integer, Object> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
```

then you should be able to put any Java object in the map.

Comment: Map **is** an interface, so `new Map<Integer, Object>();` is a fail.

Answer (score 1):

You could exploit autoboxing and use `Integer` instead of int and so forth.

The corresponding types (`Integer`, `Double`, `Bool`, ...) inherit object, so you could use a standard `Map<Object, Whatever>` and throw arbitrary stuff at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Integer` instead of `int`.